# toast positioning in angular material page

Tags: angularjs, angular-material, toast

i have a long signup form designed in angular-material. i have used toast to make UI more interactive. toast is working perfectly with its positioning too. but my html page is not fixed to its **height**, the toast appears to its position in the initial state of the page. but when i scroll down the page the toast is hidden, and i have to scroll up to see the toast. how to fixed the page height or any other way to present toast like a modal.any suggestion would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Post your code or create a codepen/plunker for your issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this style:

```
md-toast {
    position: fixed !important;
}
```

Comment: you save me diego :)